# Not Able to get email of user logged in via fb account in my site

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

I am making a site to make people login via their Facebook account.

I am able to fetch Name and the users image but I'm not getting users email. Email is returning as undefined. My code for Facebook login is:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
      appId      : 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', // Set YOUR APP ID
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
});
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) 
{
     if (response.status === 'connected') 
{
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML +=  "<br>";
}    
else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') 
{
} 
}); 
};
function Login()
{
FB.login(function(response) {
if (response.authResponse) 
{
getUserInfo();
 getPhoto();
} else 
{
 console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
}
},{scope: 'email,user_photos,user_videos'});
}
function getUserInfo() {
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
var str="You have succesfully logged in<br>";
 var name=response.name;
var email=response.email;
 console.log(name+email);
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    window.location.reload();
});
    }
    function getPhoto()
    {
FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function(response) {
var str="<br/><b>Pic</b> : <img src='"+response.data.url+"'/>";
$('#getphoto').html(str);
});
}
function Logout()
{
FB.logout(function(){document.location.reload();});
}
 // Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
```

I've tried to get the email by all ways mentioned in Stack Overflow and  developers.facebook.com, but failed.

Trigger for the Facebook login:

```
<img src='img/fblogin.jpg' onclick='login()'>
```

I tried to alert response properties by 
`for (key in response){ alert("response["+ key +"]="+ response[key]); }` 
it is returning name and id not email

Comment: I tried to alert response properties by    for (key in response){
    alert("response["+ key +"]="+ response[key]);
}    it is returning name and id not email

Answer (score 0):

```
I think issue is on your app that you have created on here https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

can you please make below changes first ?

login in https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ and open your app.

Click on "Status & Review" then find this "
Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" make it yes.

After that check did you get email or not and let me know.
```

Comment: I have already done it. Fb also showing full green signal ( live and avialable to all user message on hover).

Comment: In my Approved Items fb is showing email, public profile, user friend

Comment: ok, so can you try to login as another email address and check to get email or not. Because some time user make email hide from him/her profile.

Comment: I have tried it with three accounts in all cases i am getting name and image but not email id

Comment: @jalpa Yes, you are right.